# PHP Script didn't abort after max_execution_time (XAMPP, XDebug)

Tags: php, ajax, xampp, xdebug

I have a PHP script with infinity loop.
When I run this script using AJAX or directly in browser the server is trying to execute this script. The problem is: **After 30 seconds the server is still executing the script.** There is no *"Maximum execution time  exceeded"* error. In the php.ini file max_execution_time is set to 30. Because of this problem, server is **no longer usable**. I can't  run any other script by AJAX. I have to restart Apache in XAMPP.
**Why the server didn't abort after 30 seconds?** 
I'm using XAMPP and XDebug.

**// UPDATE 1:**
PHP Script:

```
<?php
while(true)
echo 'test';
```

I know that this code have no sense. I just wondering, why the server didn't abort execution after 30 seconds...

**//UPDATE 2: ** I turned off XDebug, and change code to:

```
<?php
$x = 0;
while(true)
   $x += 1;
```

Now it's ok: the server abort script after 30 sec with "max execution time" error.
However, the server still can't abort script with "echo" statement (even with with disabled XDebug). The same problem is when I try to execute script without "echo", but with enabled XDebug.
So, it seems to be problem when I use "echo" or "XDebug".
The script is corretly aborted only if there is no 'echo' and XDebug is disabled.

Comment: Showing us the code in question would be useful for us to help.

Comment: Done. But I think it may be XAMPP or XDebug problem.

Comment: What value do you get if you run this little script: <?php $max_execution_time = ini_get('max_execution_time');
echo $max_execution_time; ?>

Comment: Read The answer bellow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well. For me, once xdebug was enabled and autostarted, max_execution_time was set to 0 no matter what. I had to disable it to have it as a value. At least now I know that in my development environment, timeout testing is not possible while xdebug is enabled.

In my case, the script would get killed by the web server without running the register_shutdown_function. Since PHP wasn't handling the timeout, I'd get no errors except for the internal 500 error. Bugsnag wouldn't get notified.

Answer (score 1):

I have make changes in my case in:
xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php

search for : `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit']

You can change **Right hand Value** to any higher value, like '6000'.
and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Done!
I turned off "Litening for PHP Debug Connections" in PHP Storm and the problem is solved.